# XUnit: How to assert exception thrown by the controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: unit-testing, testing, assert, xunit, assertion

I have a method inside the controller, which does some checks when the check is not true, it will throw an error. How I will catch that error thrown by the API with the specific message?

I`m confused about how to make those types of assertions.

This is my code so far, but I didn't manage to catch the error thrown by the controller. What I'm doing wrong?

```
[Fact]
    public async Task AppendEmailBase64Dto_InvalidBase64_ReturnBadRequest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var emailControllerMocks = new EmailControllerMocks();
        var mockLogger = emailControllerMocks.MockLogger();
        var mockMapper = emailControllerMocks.MockMapper();
        var mockEmsWorkUnit = emailControllerMocks.MockEmsWorkUnit();
        var mockAzureBlob = emailControllerMocks.MockAzureBlobAndGetTemplate();

        // Setup
        var userRequestTemplateString = File.ReadAllText(@".\EmailController\UserRequestTemplate.txt");
        mockAzureBlob.Setup(blob => blob.GetHtmlBlob(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Uri>()))
            .ReturnsAsync(userRequestTemplateString);


        // Act
        var emailController = new Controllers.ApiV10.EmailController(mockLogger.Object, mockMapper.Object, mockEmsWorkUnit.Object, mockAzureBlob.Object);
        var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@".\EmailController\TemplateBase64Invalid.json");
        var testEmailBase64Dto = GeneralHelpers.Deserialize<EmailBase64Dto>(jsonString);

        var badRequestResult = await emailController.AppendEmailBase64Dto(testEmailBase64Dto);
        //var result = badRequestResult.Value as ObjectResult;
        //var errorMessage = badRequestResult.Value as List<string>;
        //var statusCode = badRequestResult.StatusCode;

        // Assert
        //Assert.Equal("The provided base64 template is not a valid base64 string", errorMessage[0]);
        //Assert.Equal(400, statusCode);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are throwing an exception, shouldn't "BadRequest 400" response be a result of invalid data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Assert.ThrowsAsync](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.ThrowsAsync) (the asynchronous counterpart of [Assert.Throws](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assert.Throws)) to assert that an exception of a particular type is thrown.

In your case you'll want something like:

```
var ex = await Assert.ThrowsAsync<HttpException>(async () => await emailController.AppendEmailBase64Dto(testEmailBase64Dto));
```

Obviously adjust 'HttpException' to whatever type of exception you're expecting.
You're not going to be able to check the return type in the same test (because `AppendEmailBase64Dto` will not return when an exception is thrown), so you'll need to test the exception in a separate test.

Comment: `await Assert.ThrowsAsync<HttpException>(async () => await emailController.AppendEmailBase64Dto(testEmailBase64Dto));`